# What is this plant from Morocco?

Tags: species-identification, botany

[image]The plant was photographed in spring in Morocco. It's an angiosperm. It is about 2 metres high and has feathered fruits. What species is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like *Nerium oleander* based on the leaves and the seeds/pod.  If not that species, certainly in the genus.  This is a common landscape plant in arid environments, and native to your area according to Wikipedia.  It contains extremely toxic substances that affect the heart, called cardiac glycosides.  Consuming these substances, which are found in the white latex, causes the heart to beat itself to death.

Comment: I once heard an anecdote telling that soldiers in Napoleon's army invading Spain got poisoned using this plant to make skewers.